# Error con android studio 2.3.3 >> :Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26'

Tags: android-studio

¿Qué puedo hacer para resolver el siguiente error?

```
Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: E:\ARIEL\Carrera\Programas\AndroidSDK
Install missing platform(s) and sync project
```

Actualmente tengo la version 2.3.3 de android studio, graddle 3.5 y en la carpeta SDK/plataforms tengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y tambien tengo esto cuando intento instalar nuevas API, ya lo he reinstalado varias veces y me sale lo mismo, y no se si es porque soy cubano y lo instalo sin internet o algo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Ya descargaste la api 26?

Comment: Llevo bastante tiempo navegando y presionando links para hacerlo y no puedo, muchos me dan error 404 (Not Found!)

Comment: Dentro del mismo Android Studio puedes entrar al SDK MANAGER y descargar las **API** que necesites, al igual que los `plataform_tools`.

Comment: He ahí el problema, es que eso no se hacerlo. Soy nuevo en esta IDE y desde que la tengo instalada en mi PC solo da errores

Comment: Ya te respondi con imagenes, espero te sirva, cualquier problema me comentas. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para descargar la **API 26**, debes entrar al **SDK MANAGER**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego, en la pestaña que dice **SDK PLATFORMS** seleccionas la versión que deseas descargar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo, en la pestaña **SDK TOOLS** seleccionas las herramientas necesarias como lo son **Support-Repository**, **Android-Sdk tools**, **Android-Sdk Platforms Tools** y el **Android-Sdk Build Tools**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PD:** Recuerda siempre mantener actualizadas todas estas herramientas para evitar posibles errores al compilar.

Comment: Edite la pregunta arriba para que veas lo que me pasa cuando intento hacer lo que me dices

Comment: Para instalarlos es necesario estar con conexión a Internet.